# hoodie app on nodejitsu: added %2f confounding couchdb request

Tags: couchdb, nodejitsu, hoodie

I have deployed a basic tutorial hoodie app on nodejitsu (which works fine on my local server).  Here is the url of my deployed app:

http://reggie.nodejitsu.com

A signup button is supposed to appear in the upper right hand corner after user login status is confirmed, which it does, but after a very, very long time.

Looking at the log file on nodejitsu, I see (personal detail redacted):

```
Streaming logging information

out Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:51:25 GMT Starting Plugin: 'hoodie-plugin-users'
out Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:51:25 GMT All plugins started.
err Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:51:25 GMT { [Error: not_found
missing]
```

and then a little later:

```
_header: 'GET /_users/org.couchdb.user%3Aadmin%2F HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxxxx.iriscouch.com\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nAuthorization: Basic YWRtaW46bm9uY3JpdGljYWw=\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n',
```

and then a little later:

```
out Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:51:25 GMT 
err Thu, 13 Nov 2014 18:51:25 GMT Error confirming user: Error: not_found
missing
```

If I request the endpoint `/_users/org.couchdb.user%3Aadmin%2F` from my nodejitsu couchdb instance directly, that fails with `{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}`. But if I remove the trailing encoded slash, `/_users/org.couchdb.user%3Aadmin`, I get the user returned as expected.

So it seems to me the trailing encoded slash (`%2f`) is messing up the authentication with couchdb, and then I presume the very long delay the app takes to figure out if the user is logged in to the app is resulting from a timeout trying access the database without the required credentials.  But I do not know how to stop the trailing encoded slash from being added.

Have I diagnosed the issue correctly, and either way, how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you have a user document for the CouchDB user "admin" in your _users database, which should not exist. CouchDB admin users don't have own documents in the `_users` database. The Hoodie error you get is because of the wrong format of the _users object and the missing user database. When you remove `/_users/org.couchdb.user%3Aadmin%2F` it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is correct, but once I made these changes and restarted app, I am getting 404 Not Found errors for all my assets under /vendor/assets (including vital javascript files), which seems to me unrelated at reggie.jit.su, and reroute to some undefined admin console at reggie.nodejitsu.com.  Maybe time to just start over with nodejitsu deployment.